# How to rephrase so I don't use "I" or "you" or any other pronouns?

Tags: pronouns

**I hope I helped you see this situation more clearly** is the sentence that I need to rephrase, and my English teacher shot down the idea of **this should help everyone see the situation more clearly** because she said that I can't *tell* the readers that that they should see it clearly. You know what I'm saying? Oh, and one more thing. The essay is a compare and contrast essay about contacts and glasses, so the words see and clearly have to be in the sentence, to make it a pun. Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: Any thoughts on the matter would help, even if it doesn't answer the question. I have to turn in the paper tomorrow, so please try to answer! I am thinking really hard, but my smarticles are seeming to fail me. Sorry I just had to type that. Thanks! :)

Comment: Has the teacher specified what the point of this excercise is? You might as well try to avoid *the*, or *more*, or the letter *C*. It's a one-off riddle, a mindless pastime. It doesn't teach a particular skill useful for anything. The question is highly localized and unlikely to help anyone except yourself, and indeed won't be of any use even to yourself as soon as tomorrow.

Comment: I understand where the teacher is coming from here. The exercise just doesn't address *why* to do things differently, which means it isn't going to be that much help in the long run.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about conforming to arbitrary restrictions. It's more of a word puzzle than a question about English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 3):

> The situation can be seen clearly.

Comment: Oh my gosh! This is absolutely perfect! Thanks so much! Sorry for overreacting. :D

Answer (score 2):

Generally, sentences along the lines of "hopefully this helps the reader see that..." or "because of this, the reader can clearly understand that..." should be avoided. Your essay needs to *demonstrate* to the reader what you want them to understand: telling the reader that they *should* understand is both redundant and presumptuous. It's redundant because the purpose of an essay in the first place is to help the reader understand a point of view. It's presumptuous because the reader may *not* understand, through your shortcomings or theirs, or they may disagree with you.

If you're drawing a conclusion from a set of arguments, try "due to this" or "as a result". If you're concluding the essay, you can briefly reiterate your major points and restate your thesis, as such:

"Since granola is high in nutrients and can be delicious if prepared properly, it should be considered as a healthy alternative for sugar cereal."

TL;DR version: try not to refer to the reader or yourself directly, since this is too casual for something as formal as an essay. Refer directly to your arguments, points, and thesis, and don't make assumptions about what the reader does or does not understand.

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, I know it is pointless, as all the students think, but I still have to turn it in. Please try to include an example sentence that could be used. I'm really sorry, this is my first time I have ever had to rely on ask websites. Thanks :)

Comment: Let me get one thing straight...it's a *requirement* from the teacher that you use the words "see" and "clearly" in the same sentence as a pun?

Comment: No...... It would be just for fun. I just wanted to see if there was any possibly way to make it work @txteclipse

Comment: Perhaps you could help me out with another question. What does TL;DR mean, I'm seeing it all over the place on this site ... (scrathes head)

Comment: @Araucaria: Too Long; Didn't Read.

Answer (score 0):

> It is to be hoped that this brings the situation into focus.

Although I agree with the comments that this is rather a pointless exercise.

Answer (score 0):

> This argument (or *presentation* or *suggestion* or whatever) may shed some light on the problem (or *situation* or whatever).

or

> ... may bring (or maybe *lend*) some clarity to ...